# BigQuery: Mod operator returning negative result when dividing by positive integer

Tags: google-bigquery, sharding, modulo

I have a table with a couple of fields. The first field is the `userId`. I am using the hash function to shard the data by userId.

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT userId, HASH(userId) as hashedId, HASH(userId) % 3 as hashedIdMod3
FROM mydataset.mytable LIMIT 1000
```

So for example:

```
-5655326518438853587 % 3 ==> -1 when it should be 2
HASH(27315207816077732041734307321022553299) is -3139846784539570547 and the remainder is -2 when divided by 3 when it should be 1
```

So, how can the remainder be negative when dividing by a positive integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod of a negative number is negative in SQL (and c++, java, etc). So you'll want to use  `ABS()` -- as in:

```
SELECT userId, 
  HASH(userId) as hashedId, 
  ABS(HASH(userId) % 3) as hashedIdMod3
FROM mydataset.mytable LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Yeah, switched to ABS() already. Any idea why is it negative in SQL and other languages? shouldn't it always be positive when dividing by a positive integer?

Comment: I don't know why ... the modulo wikipedia page has much more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: I learned something new: `But in a language where modulo has the sign of the dividend, that is incorrect, because when n (the dividend) is negative and odd, n % 2 returns −1, and the function returns false.`